# Quick bit unpacking with MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have an array of 10-bit values packed into consecutive 8-bit integers. In python, I unpack these with:

```
def unpack_10bit(data, nx, ny):
    packed = np.frombuffer(data, dtype='uint8').astype('uint16')
    unpacked = np.zeros([ny, nx], dtype='uint16')

    unpacked.flat[::4] = (packed[::5] << 2) | (packed[1::5] >> 6)
    unpacked.flat[1::4] = ((packed[1::5] & 0b00111111) << 4) | (packed[2::5] >> 4)
    unpacked.flat[2::4] = ((packed[2::5] & 0b00001111) << 6) | (packed[3::5] >> 2)
    unpacked.flat[3::4] = ((packed[3::5] & 0b00000011) << 8) | packed[4::5]

    return unpacked
```

In MATLAB, I do it like this, but it is slow:

```
dat = fread(f,imsize,'uint8');                       % read in data
tmp = dec2bin(dat);
bits = reshape(tmp',[1,length(dat)*8]);              % reshape into long vector

unpacked = zeros(nx,ny,'uint16');                    % initialise
for k = 1:(nx*ny)                                    % for each point in the array
    unpacked(k) = bin2dec(bits((k-1)*10+1 : 10*k));  % convert the 10 bits into a decimal
end
```

Any suggestions for improving the performance of the MATLAB version?

Comment: [`bitshift`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitshift.html), [`bitand`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitand.html) and [`bitor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitor.html) are the functions you're looking for. You can do exactly the same indexing tricks you're doing in Python.

Comment: Feel free to write an answer. I think this is quite an interesting question!

Answer (score 0):

This solution was:

```
packed= fread(f,h.nx*h.ny*1.25,'uint16');
unpacked= zeros(h.nx,h.ny,'uint16');

unpacked(1:4:end) = bitor(bitshift(packed(1:5:end),2),bitshift(packed(2:5:end),-6));
unpacked(2:4:end) = bitor(bitshift(bitand(packed(2:5:end),63),4),bitshift(packed(3:5:end),-4));
unpacked(3:4:end) = bitor(bitshift(bitand(packed(3:5:end),15),6),bitshift(packed(4:5:end),-2));
unpacked(4:4:end) = bitor(bitshift(bitand(packed(4:5:end),3),8),packed(5:5:end));
```

Takes 0.23s to unpack 2.6 million values. If anyone has suggestions for more speed that'd be great!

Comment: When I had to do this in Matlab I reverted to a `mex` c++ function to get the speed I needed (in my case the order of magnitude improvement was in the 100's)